# XSLT 1.0 - Replace text string in node when condition(s) match

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to overwrite/replace part of a string when the conditions match using XSLT 1.0

`Destination` *always* contains the text string `-MyEnc480p-AC3-CRF19.mkv`

However the title at the beginning can vary e.g. `MyVideo1-MyEnc480p-AC3-CRF19.mkv` or `MyVideo2-MyEnc480p-AC3-CRF19.mkv` etc.

*Intended outcome:*

When the `AudioTrack/TrackNumber = 1` and `AudioTrack/Description contains = AAC`

in the node `Destination` the text `AC3` becomes replaced with `AAC`

i.e. `MyVideo1-MyEnc480p-AC3-CRF19.mkv` should change to `MyVideo1-MyEnc480p-AAC-CRF19.mkv`

Here is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  >

    <!-- copy all nodes and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match item where the trackNumber = 1 and contains text = AAC -->
<xsl:template match="AudioTracks(AudioTrack(ScannedTrack/TrackNumber) = 1 and (ScannedTrack/Description) contains = AAC)]">

    <xsl:template match="Destination">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

            <!-- replace text AC3 with AAC -->
        <xsl:when test="contains('AC3')">
        <xsl:sequence select="replace('AC3', 'AAC')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the XML that I am working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfQueueTask xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <QueueTask>
    <IsNotifying>true</IsNotifying>
    <ScannedSourcePath>C:\VIDEO\MyVideo.mkv</ScannedSourcePath>
    <Status>Waiting</Status>
    <Task>
      <IsNotifying>true</IsNotifying>
      <ShowAdvancedTab>false</ShowAdvancedTab>
      <AudioTracks>
        <AudioTrack>
          <IsNotifying>true</IsNotifying>
          <ScannedTrack>
            <TrackNumber>1</TrackNumber>
            <Language>English</Language>
            <LanguageCode>eng</LanguageCode>
            <Description>English (AAC LC) (2.0 ch)</Description>
            <Codec>65536</Codec>
            <SampleRate>48000</SampleRate>
            <Bitrate>1</Bitrate>
            <ChannelLayout>3</ChannelLayout>
          </ScannedTrack>
          <Encoder>AacPassthru</Encoder>
          <IsDefault>false</IsDefault>
        </AudioTrack>
      </AudioTracks>
     <Source>C:\VIDEO\MyVideo.mkv</Source>
      <Title>1</Title>
      <Angle>1</Angle>
      <PointToPointMode>Chapters</PointToPointMode>
      <StartPoint>1</StartPoint>
      <EndPoint>1</EndPoint>
      <Destination>C:\Temp\MyVideo-MyEnc480p-AC3-CRF19.mkv</Destination>
      <OutputFormat>Mkv</OutputFormat>
      <OptimizeMP4>false</OptimizeMP4>
      <IPod5GSupport>false</IPod5GSupport>
      <AlignAVStart>false</AlignAVStart>
    </Task>
  </QueueTask>
</ArrayOfQueueTask>
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is not entirely clear. Assuming you want to modify `Destination` when the `Description` of the `ScannedTrack` whose `TrackNumber` is `1` contains `"AAC"`, you could do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Destination[contains(../AudioTracks/AudioTrack/ScannedTrack[TrackNumber=1]/Description, 'AAC')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-MyEnc480p-AC3-CRF19.mkv')" />
        <xsl:text>-MyEnc480p-AAC-CRF19.mkv</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>            
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Re your attempt:

- Templates cannot be nested;
- `xsl:sequence` and `replace()` require XSLT 2.0;
- Predicates use square brackets.

Comment: PS - Appreciate the comments also on my attempt, helping me to learn. I was actually using square brackets then changed them back as I thought they were incorrect.